# How to auto increment the date value in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to auto increment the date value in vb.net?

```
Name - asdf
From Date - 23/02/2009
To Date - 12/03/2009
```

From Date and To Date is Datepicker column

When i click the add Button, from Date should display in the textbox, then again i click the 
add button the next date should display in the textbox. The date should increment upto To Date.

From the above table

```
When i click Add button means - 23/02/2009 should display
Again i click the add button - 24/02/2009 Should display
```

It should display up to 12/03/2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Console.WriteLine(today.ToString())
Dim newDay As DateTime = today.AddDays(1)
Console.WriteLine(newDay.ToString())
```

Call currentDay.AddDays(1) on every button click.